# Can't save my combobox items to MyStringCollection in appSettings

Tags: c#

I'm developing a win app and somewhere i have to insert items to the combobox.
But when i restart the app, the items are not there anymore
I used a string collection for saving them.
Of course it reads the items but it doesn't save the settings in it.
Here is my code
Thanks for your helps.

In my Form_load

```
private void Services_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.combo_items != null)
    {
        foreach (object items in Properties.Settings.Default.combo_items)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(items);
        }
    }
}
```

In my form_closing

```
 private void Services_Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.combo_items != null)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.combo_items.Clear();
        foreach (string items in combo_Combobox_1.Items)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.combo_items.Add(items);
        }
    }
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I have also add and remove some strings to the value of string collection at first.

Comment: Did you have defined them as ApplicationSettings or UserSettings?

Comment: i've defined them as user settings

Comment: Is there any libraries i have to insert????!!!!

Comment: i'm really confused. i'm working on it for 3 days but i didn't have reach to results.

Comment: I suggest you try to put a breakpoint in Services_Form_FormClosing and see if it goes through the code. (If you havn't done it already.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem where is.
In Form_closing

```
private void Services_Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.combo_main_srvc.Clear();

            foreach (object items in combo_delete_main_srvc.Items)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.combo_main_srvc.Add(items.ToString());
            }
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

I replaced the object instead of string in `foreach` condition.